# instance variable unchanged after updating my multiple processes

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

For the following code, I expect the output of `dr.hello` to be **10**, since 10 spawned processes call `updateHello` once to increment `dr.hello`. But it is now **0**, what is the reason and how do I change it?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

class myWorker:
    def __init__(self, lock, driver, i):
        self.idx=i
        self.driver=driver
        self.lock=lock

    def run(self):
        self.driver.updateHello(self.lock,self.idx)

class driver:
    hello=0
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock=Lock()

    def workerrun(self,lock, i):
        worker1=myWorker(lock,self,i)
        worker1.run()

    def run(self):
        D=[Process(target=self.workerrun,args=(self.lock,i)) for i in range(10)]
        for d in D:
            d.start()
        for d in D:
            d.join()

    def updateHello(self,l,i):
        l.acquire()
        self.hello+=1
        print "update from",i
        l.release()

if __name__=='__main__':
    dr=driver()
    dr.run()
    print dr.hello
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a [multiprocessing.Value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) for a shared variable

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Value

class myWorker:
    def __init__(self, lock, driver, i):
        self.idx=i
        self.driver=driver
        self.lock=lock

    def run(self):
        self.driver.updateHello(self.lock,self.idx)

class driver:
    hello = Value("i",lock=True) # create shared variable of type int
    hello.value = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.lock=Lock()

    def workerrun(self,lock, i):
        worker1=myWorker(lock,self,i)
        worker1.run()

    def run(self):
        D=[Process(target=self.workerrun,args=(self.lock,i)) for i in range(10)]
        for d in D:
            d.start()
        for d in D:
            d.join()

    def updateHello(self,l,i):
        with self.lock: # acquire lock
            driver.hello.value += 1
            print ("update from", i)
        # release lock

if __name__=='__main__':
    dr=driver()
    dr.run()
    print(driver.hello.value)
```

Ipython output:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    dr=driver()
    dr.run()
    print(driver.hello.value)

## -- End pasted text --
('update from', 0)
('update from', 1)
('update from', 2)
('update from', 5)
('update from', 6)
('update from', 7)
('update from', 4)
('update from', 3)
('update from', 8)
('update from', 9)
10
```

Comment: It is ten for me, I added the full code I ran and the ipython output

Comment: Strangely, I run in python by copy and paste your code..it gives me 0. Maybe you can try for normal python rather than IPython?

Comment: I am using pycharm too...with windows 7

Comment: that is weird, I am also using python 2.7 so there is no reason I can see why it would not work, have you copied all the code exactly as posted?

Comment: I am using linux so unless there is some windows specific reason which I don't see anything about in the docs it should work. It really is odd

Comment: Hmm...but the (correct version of) program here http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing does give me 500. I am seeing what is the different here..

Comment: I post a workable version (on my computer), I do it by changing  the class variable to instance variable in your solution.

Comment: out of interest does changing to  `self.hello.value += 1` make any difference?

Comment: I am also changing the `hello =...` to `self.hello=..` but I am entirely not sure what makes the difference

Comment: well all I know is either works for  me, I would be interested to know why it does not work for you

Comment: The difference in behavior is because the same `Value` object gets inherited by the children on Linux, because of `os.fork()`, but it ends up getting completely re-created in the children on Windows, because it has to re-import the `__main__` module, which means the `driver` class gets re-executed.

Comment: @dano, thanks for explaining but why does windows behave differently?

Comment: Windows doesn't support `fork`, so each child has to  re-import the entire module, which means `hello` gets redefined. Linux can `fork` so no re-import is needed; each child gets a copy-on-write version of `hello`, which will all write to the same shared memory area.

Answer (score 0):

This works now, I do it by changing Padraic solution from class variable to instance variable

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Value

class myWorker:
    def __init__(self, lock, driver, i):
        self.idx=i
        self.driver=driver
        self.lock=lock

    def run(self):
        self.driver.updateHello(self.lock,self.idx)

class driver(object):
    #hello = Value("i",lock=True) # create shared variable of type int
    #hello.value = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.lock=Lock()
        self.hello=Value("i",0)

    def workerrun(self,lock, i):
        worker1=myWorker(lock,self,i)
        worker1.run()

    def run(self):
        D=[Process(target=self.workerrun,args=(self.lock,i)) for i in range(10)]
        for d in D:
            d.start()
        for d in D:
            d.join()

    def updateHello(self,l,i):
        with self.lock: # acquire lock
            self.hello.value += 1
            print ("update from", i)
        # release lock

if __name__=='__main__':
    dr=driver()
    dr.run()
    print(dr.hello.value)
```